# How to solve or approximately solvea differential equation with a integral item in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to solve the equation group like
\frac{dx_1(t)}{dt}&=(1-\int_0^t x_1(t) dt)x_2+x_1; 
\frac{dx_2(t)}{dt}&=(1-\int_0^t x_2(t) dt)x_1+x_2.
Can I directly use the methods in Matlab to solve this problem? I tried ode45 but failed.

Comment: Please write the equation in a correct format.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and the problem you encountered in your question.